# Scroll to section on page load (mobile)

Tags: jquery, mobile

I would like to auto-scroll to section after page load ONLY on mobile.
I use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if ( $(window).width() < 768 || window.Touch) {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#header-main").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    }
});
```

It works, but scroll is active on each screen size, desktop too.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this condition instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (!!('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints)) {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#header-main").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```